# Django Oscar Razorpay Integration

Tags: python, django, payment-gateway, django-oscar, razorpay

I'm trying to integrate Razorpay payment gateway to a default Django-Oscar project. I'm not sure how to pass the checkout.js generated payment id to Django server to capture payment.

As per my limited understanding, the checkout.js code of Razorpay generates a unique payment id after every time the user fills up the payment information and initiates authorization.

**payment_details.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'checkout:preview' %}" method="POST">
<!-- Note that the amount is in its subunit value = 599 -->
<script
    src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"
    data-key="rzp_test_XXUUnffGta42gL"
    data-amount="{{ order_total_incl_tax_cents }}"
    data-currency="INR"
    data-buttontext="Pay with Razorpay"
    data-name="{{ shop_name }}"
    data-description="{{ basket.num_items }} items ({{ order_total.incl_tax|currency }})"
    data-image="https://your-awesome-site.com/your_logo.jpg"
    data-prefill.name="Gaurav Kumar"
    data-prefill.email="test@test.com"
    data-theme.color="#F37254"
></script>
<input type="hidden" value="Hidden Element" name="hidden">
</form>
```

I have forked the checkout app.

**checkout/__init__.py**

```
PAYMENT_EVENT_PURCHASE = 'Purchase'
PAYMENT_METHOD_STRIPE = 'Razorpay'
RAZORPAY_EMAIL = 'razorpayEmail'
RAZORPAY_TOKEN = 'razorpayToken'

default_app_config = 'checkout.apps.CheckoutConfig'
```

**checkout/forms.py**

```
class StripeTokenForm(forms.Form):
    razorpayEmail = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    razorpayToken = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

**checkout/views.py**

```
class PaymentDetailsView(CorePaymentDetailsView):

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(PaymentDetailsView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(PaymentDetailsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.preview:
            ctx['razorpay_token_form'] = forms.RazorpayTokenForm(self.request.POST)
            ctx['order_total_incl_tax_cents'] = (
                ctx['order_total'].incl_tax * 100
            ).to_integral_value()
        else:
            ctx['order_total_incl_tax_cents'] = (
                    ctx['order_total'].incl_tax * 100
            ).to_integral_value()
            ctx['razorpay_publishable_key'] = settings.RAZORPAY_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
        return ctx

    def handle_payment(self, order_number, total, **kwargs):
        razorpay_ref = Facade().charge(
            order_number,
            total,
            card=self.request.POST[RAZORPAY_TOKEN],
            description=self.payment_description(order_number, total, **kwargs),
            metadata=self.payment_metadata(order_number, total, **kwargs))

        source_type, __ = SourceType.objects.get_or_create(name=PAYMENT_METHOD_RAZORPAY)
        source = Source(
            source_type=source_type,
            currency=settings.RAZORPAY_CURRENCY,
            amount_allocated=total.incl_tax,
            amount_debited=total.incl_tax,
            reference=razorpay_ref)
        self.add_payment_source(source)

        self.add_payment_event(PAYMENT_EVENT_PURCHASE, total.incl_tax)

    def payment_description(self, order_number, total, **kwargs):
        return self.request.POST[RAZORPAY_EMAIL]

    def payment_metadata(self, order_number, total, **kwargs):
        return {'order_number': order_number}
```

**checkout/facade.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from oscar.apps.payment.exceptions import UnableToTakePayment, InvalidGatewayRequestError

import razorpay


class Facade(object):
    def __init__(self):
        client = razorpay.Client(auth=("rzp_test_XXUUnrrBmW42gL", "32Cqrj2UvxOT24nUbtO7Zacr"))

    @staticmethod
    def get_friendly_decline_message(error):
        return 'The transaction was declined by your bank - please check your bankcard details and try again'

    @staticmethod
    def get_friendly_error_message(error):
        return 'An error occurred when communicating with the payment gateway.'

    def charge(self,
        order_number,
        total,
        card,
        currency=settings.STRIPE_CURRENCY,
        description=None,
        metadata=None,
        **kwargs):
        try:
            return client.payment.capture(card, total)
        except razorpay.error.CardError as e:
            raise UnableToTakePayment(self.get_friendly_decline_message(e))
        except razorpay.error.RazorpayError as e:
            raise InvalidGatewayRequestError(self.get_friendly_error_message(e))
```

As Razorpay checkout process is similar to Stripe, I have used the same checkout process as Stripe integration. If only I could get the frontend generated payment id, payment capture can be successful.